# How to query to Fetch Data of each Name in List for a Date Range

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, qsqlquery, unnest

I have a table like

| Name | Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2020-12-01 |
| B | 5 | 2020-12-01 |
| A | 10 | 2020-12-02 |
| B | 15 | 2020-12-02 |

now I have a List of Name and Date List Like

```
@NameList = '[A],[B],[C],[D]'
@DateList =  '[2020-12-01],[2020-12-02],[2020-12-03],[2020-12-04]'
```

How to query to fetch data for each name and date available in `@NameList` and `@DateList`?

Expected Result

| Name | Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2020-12-01 |
| B | 5 | 2020-12-01 |
| C | 0 | 2020-12-01 |
| D | 0 | 2020-12-01 |
| A | 10 | 2020-12-02 |
| B | 15 | 2020-12-02 |
| c | 0 | 2020-12-02 |
| D | 0 | 2020-12-02 |
| A | 0 | 2020-12-03 |
| B | 0 | 2020-12-03 |
| c | 0 | 2020-12-03 |
| D | 0 | 2020-12-03 |
| A | 0 | 2020-12-04 |
| B | 0 | 2020-12-04 |
| c | 0 | 2020-12-04 |
| D | 0 | 2020-12-04 |

Comment: Hi @DaleK , Name List And Date Rand Coming From UI

Answer (score 0):

How about a JSON approach?

Assuming that the names and dates never contain a double quote, you can turn them to JSON strings with string functions, and unnest each list as rows with `openjson()`. The last step is to bring the original table with a `left join`.

```
declare @NameList nvarchar(max) = '[A],[B],[C],[D]';
declare @DateList nvarchar(max) =  '[2020-12-01],[2020-12-02],[2020-12-03],[2020-12-04]';

select n.name, coalesce(t.total, 0) as total, d.dt 
from openjson('[' + replace(replace(@NameList, '[', '"'), ']', '"') + ']') 
    with(name nvarchar(max) '$') n
cross join openjson('[' + replace(replace(@DateList, '[', '"'), ']', '"') + ']') 
    with(dt date '$') d
left join mytable t on t.name = n.name and t.date = d.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break apart the lists using `string_split()` and then use `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
declare @NameList nvarchar(max) = '[A],[B],[C],[D]';
declare @DateList nvarchar(max) =  '[2020-12-01],[2020-12-02],[2020-12-03],[2020-12-04]';

select v.name, v.date, coalesce(t.total, 0) as total
from string_split(@namelist, ',') n cross join
     string_split(@datelist, ',') d cross apply
     (values (replace(replace(n.value, '[', ''), ']', ''),  
              convert(date, replace(replace(d.value, '[', ''), ']', ''))
             )
     ) v(name, date) left join
     yourtable t
     on t.name = v.name and t.date = v.date
```

The only real trick here is to use `apply` to remove the square braces.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b301ec5c0a07e2b169b821fa0c99e3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
select t1.name,t2.[date]  from 
[table] t1
cross apply [table] t2
```

Comment: Please illustrate how this solves the OPs problem? It doesn't appear to take into account any of the ranges concerned.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.